# How can I configure xorg to use only the GPU connected to the display in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 22.10

I have two gpu, a display is connected to one gpu, xorg works on both gpu taking up several MB of video memory on the second gpu, is there any way to prohibit him from using a gpu to which the display is not connected? Ubuntu 22.10.